# Setting up a cron Job

Tags: cron, jobs

Please I am new to cron jobs and only heard of it recently.

The thing is I am trying to send a message to myself via a phpscript.

I need the cron job to read the php cript and send the appropriate message.

here is the php self mailer I have in place.

```
<?php
    $recipient = "*******@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Flight Status";
    $body = "Flight has just landed.";
    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $body))
    {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent</p>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<p>Message Delivery failed </p>");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can read the manual for cron with man 5 crontab. It contain example as well.
for example,

# run at 2:15pm on the first of every month -- output mailed to paul

15 14 1 * *     $HOME/bin/flight.php

Comment: thanks alot. Please could you attach a recommended link to read on it.

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5 or you can type the command, man 5 crontab in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email through phone is complicated, as you need a smtp server set up. A better solution would be to send yourself a message via a chat application.

I personally use nimrod for this : https://www.nimrod-messenger.io 
It's messenger only but other chat systems are planned.